# Изминение скорости прорутки ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Есть следующий код кастомного ViewPager'a с вертикальной прокруткой. Меня интересует, возможно ли как то изменить скорость этой прокрутки. Я использую ViewPager 
вместе с анимацией других элементов и скорости не совпадают, в анимации скорость конечно могу поменять но это проблему не решает, т.к. скорость остается высокой, а надо наоборот - понизить!

```
public class CustomViewPagerV extends ViewPager {

    private boolean isPagingEnabled = true;

    public CustomViewPagerV(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomViewPagerV(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(); // initialize vertical scrolling
    }


    public void setPagingEnabled(boolean b) {
        this.isPagingEnabled = b;
    }



    private void init() {
        // The majority of the magic happens here
        setPageTransformer(true, new VerticalPageTransformer());
        // The easiest way to get rid of the overscroll drawing that happens on the left and right
        setOverScrollMode(OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);

    }

    /**
     * Swaps the X and Y coordinates of your touch event.
     */
    private MotionEvent swapXY(MotionEvent ev) {
        float width = getWidth();
        float height = getHeight();

        float newX = (ev.getY() / height) * width;
        float newY = (ev.getX() / width) * height;

        ev.setLocation(newX, newY);

        return ev;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
        boolean intercepted = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));
        swapXY(ev); // return touch coordinates to original reference frame for any child views
        return this.isPagingEnabled && intercepted;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return this.isPagingEnabled && super.onTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));
    }


    private class VerticalPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

        @Override
        public void transformPage(View view, float position) {

            if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
                // This page is way off-screen to the left.
                view.setAlpha(0);

            } else if (position <= 1) { // [-1,1]
                view.setAlpha(1);

                // Counteract the default slide transition
                view.setTranslationX(view.getWidth() * -position);

                //set Y position to swipe in from top
                float yPosition = -(position * view.getHeight()); 
                view.setTranslationY(yPosition);

            } else { // (1,+Infinity]
                // This page is way off-screen to the right.
                view.setAlpha(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вот тут решение посмотрите  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155257/slowing-speed-of-viewpager-controller-in-android

Comment: @АндроидАндроид спасибо, то что надо!